# To index geojson data to elasticsearch using curl

Tags: elasticsearch, curl, geojson

I'd like to index a `geojson` data to elasticsearch using curl

The geojson data looks like this:

```json
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "telco_new_development",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ogc_fid": 1, "name": "Yarrabilba", "carrier_name": "OptiComm", "uid": "35", "development_name": "Yarrabilba", "stage": "None", "developer_name": "Refer to Carrier", "development_nature": "Residential", "development_type": "Sub-division", "estimated_number_of_lots_or_units": "18500", "status": "Ready for service", "developer_application_date": "Check with carrier", "contract_date": "TBC", "estimated_service_date": "30 Jul 2013", "technology_type": "FTTP", "last_modified_date": "8 Jul 2020" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 153.101112, -27.797998 ], [ 153.09786, -27.807122 ], [ 153.097715, -27.816313 ], [ 153.100598, -27.821068 ], [ 153.103789, -27.825047 ], [ 153.106079, -27.830225 ], [ 153.108248, -27.836107 ], [ 153.110692, -27.837864 ], [ 153.116288, -27.840656 ], [ 153.119923, -27.844818 ], [ 153.122317, -27.853523 ], [ 153.127785, -27.851777 ], [ 153.131234, -27.85115 ], [ 153.135634, -27.849741 ], [ 153.138236, -27.848668 ], [ 153.141703, -27.847075 ], [ 153.152205, -27.84496 ], [ 153.155489, -27.843381 ], [ 153.158613, -27.841546 ], [ 153.161937, -27.84059 ], [ 153.156361, -27.838492 ], [ 153.157097, -27.83451 ], [ 153.15036, -27.832705 ], [ 153.151126, -27.827536 ], [ 153.15169, -27.822564 ], [ 153.148492, -27.820801 ], [ 153.148375, -27.817969 ], [ 153.139019, -27.815804 ], [ 153.139814, -27.808556 ], [ 153.126486, -27.80576 ], [ 153.124679, -27.803584 ], [ 153.120764, -27.802953 ], [ 153.121397, -27.797353 ], [ 153.100469, -27.79362 ], [ 153.099828, -27.793327 ], [ 153.101112, -27.797998 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ogc_fid": 2, "name": "Elliot Springs", "carrier_name": "OptiComm", "uid": "63", "development_name": "Elliot Springs", "stage": "None", "developer_name": "Refer to Carrier", "development_nature": "Residential", "development_type": "Sub-division", "estimated_number_of_lots_or_units": "11674", "status": "Ready for service", "developer_application_date": "Check with carrier", "contract_date": "TBC", "estimated_service_date": "29 Nov 2018", "technology_type": "FTTP", "last_modified_date": "8 Jul 2020" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 146.862725, -19.401424 ], [ 146.865987, -19.370253 ], [ 146.872767, -19.370901 ], [ 146.874484, -19.354706 ], [ 146.874913, -19.354301 ], [ 146.877059, -19.356811 ], [ 146.87972, -19.35835 ], [ 146.889161, -19.359321 ], [ 146.900062, -19.367581 ], [ 146.884955, -19.38507 ], [ 146.88341, -19.402558 ], [ 146.862725, -19.401424 ] ] ] ] } },
...
```

However, my curl is returns an error called `The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]`

```sh
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST 'localhost:9200/geo/building/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @building.geojson
```

```sh
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\\n]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: aside from my answer, how much data is this? are you tied to that document structure?

Comment: Hi @MarkWalkom, the dataset is about 15MB include around 13K polygons. I've tried drag and drop to Kibana Map and the file is valid. But I just wanna figure out a way to upload directly using curl

Comment: you could use something like Filebeat or Logstash or https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/connect-to-elasticsearch.html#upload-data-kibana to do this, otherwise you'll need to adhere to the structure below

Answer (score 1):

your format is not suitable for `_bulk` like that, as it's missing the structure it expects. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html goes into that

you need;

- to update your json file to have something like `{ "index" : { "_index" : "INDEX-NAME-HERE" } }` before each of the documents
- each document also needs to be on a single line
- each line needs a `\n` at the end of it so that the bulk API knows when the action/record ends